# Deleting elements of a dynamic array one-by-one

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

I want to delete a dynamically-allocated array by looping through all the elements and calling `delete` on each of them.
(I am doing this because I have to "move" an array to another location, that is, to copy the original array and then delete it, but that would take 2x the time than simultaneously copying each element and calling `delete` on them individually)

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int *n=new int[2];
    delete n;
    delete (n+1);
}
```

But i am getting a Segmentation error each time i run this....

Although, this works fine -:

```
int main()
{
    int *n=new int[1];
    delete n;
}
```

So, my guess is that delete is somehow deleting the whole array instead of a single element!

Could anyone please explain if my guess is right, and if it is, suggest a possible workaround?

I am using GCC 4.7.3 on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: The most simplest way to do that is using C++ standard containers (`std::vector` in this case) instead of dynamic arrays, and simply use the erase method of the container. But, on the other hand, what are you trying to do? Why you want to delete elements one-by-one?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to make another vector-like container of my own. [ Just to gain a better understanding of how `std::vectors` work under the hood ]

Comment: @Ammol to learn C++? ok. So your question is about the destructor of the vector? This is why you were trying to delete one element by one?

Comment: Ummm.. kind of! .. As mentioned in the question, I was trying to copy the array to another location and deallocate the original array... [ I was trying to mimic `std::vector::resize()` operation ]

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing earlier. Thanks for the help anyways. :)

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Under the hood, `std::vector` separates allocation from initialization, and so requires the use of placement new and explicit delete.  (Any implementation of something similar should do the same.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot delete the elements individually. When you allocate with `new []` you must deallocate with `delete []`. What you are doing here:

```
int *n=new int[1];
delete n;  // ERROR: should be delete []
```

it not correct. You are invoking *undefined behaviour*. It seems to work by pure chance and cannot be relied on.

As for a workaround, it isn't clear what the problem is, but if you want to "move" the array, you could just assign it to a different pointer:

```
int* n=new int[2];
...
int* m = n;
n = nullptr;
....
delete [] m;
```

Comment: Yes, but what was wrong in `delete (n+1)`? Aren't the individual memory blocks allocated with `new` only??!

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi It is not allowed by the C++ standard.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi the point is that `new []` allocates a whole array. It doesn't make sense to de-allocate single elements of the array. What could the OS possibly do with them?

Answer (score 1):

To delete

```
int *n=new int[2];
```

use

```
delete [] n;
```

the code

```
delete n;
```

is wrong when you allocate using new [].